# How do I use "tel", "number", or other input types in WTForms?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I want to use a phone number field in my form. What I need is when this field is tapped on Android phone, not general keyboard, but digital only appears.

I learned that this can be achieved by using `<input type="tel"` or `<input type="number"`.

How do I use the tel or number input types in WTForms?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In WTForms >= 3.0, they are defined along with other common fields, and can be imported from `wtforms.fields`.

```py
from wtforms.fields import TelField

phone_number = TelField()
```

---

Previously, they were available from `wtforms.fields.html5`. They were missing from the docs until [version 2.3](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#html5-fields).

```py
from wtforms.fields.html5 import TelField
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I found it.

IntegerField(widget = widgets.Input(input_type="tel"))